# Why Doesn't a Global Var Declared in one VB6 project Compile in Another Project in same VB6 Project Group?

Tags: variables, vb6, global

I apologize that this is such an elementary question.

Our VB6 project group contains 6 projects plus the UI project containing all the app's forms.

We generate a uniqueID (gstrUniqueImportUuid) in the code behind one of the forms, which must be exposed to a class in another project in the project group.

I've tried declaring this variable as a global variable in the Common.bas module that's part of the main UI project, like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public gstrUniqueImportUuid As String
```

I then assign a value to gstrUniqueImportUuid in the form, which works fine.

But then when I try to use that global variable's value in one of the other projects in the group, that project won't compile--"variable not defined".

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Modules are not public outside of the Project. What you want to do is create a class and set it's instancing to GlobalMultiUse. Any public properties of that class will be visible to any project referencing that project. Note you con only do this for ActiveX DLLs and ActiveX EXEs.

Comment: Is that the whole reason you can't declare something as `Friend` inside of a module?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a bit now, but does the "other project" where you try to use the variable have a reference to the "UI project"? The Ui project must be checked in the references list in menu project->references.

Usually it's the UI project that is referencing one or more other projects but not the other way around. Even if the variable is global the project where it is declared in must be referenced.

If the reference doesn't exist and you can't add the reference (you might be getting circular dependencies)  you can move the declaration of the field gstrUniqueImportUuid to one of the other projects .bas files. The project you move it to (if not the "other project" must be referenced to by the UI project (and the "other project")

Comment: Thank you, @Jonas.  Unfortunately, I have tried moving the declaration of gstrUniqueImportUuid to a module in a 3rd project (named "sIECommon") that is referenced by BOTH the UI and "the other project" in which I'm trying to use the variable.  Even then, "the other project" still doesn't compile.

Comment: Ok sorry. Just putting it in the "other project", letting the UI project reference it, doesn't work either? It

Comment: I think It should work as you've done from the beginning. I'd try these things too, Try adding it a function Public Public Function GetUniqueImportUuid() As String
  GetUniqueImportUuid = gstrUniqueImportUuid
End Function and call  GetUniqueImportUuid() from your Ui project. Do you get a similar error message?  Add the declaration of the function to a common class/object that you already reference from your projects and call it on that class/object.

Comment: Thank you VERY much, @Jonas.  The combination of all your suggestions has gotten me over the hump--it now compiles.